# ResourceLoader null for simple Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple logging app that is based on spring-boot and created with gradle. What could be the root problem for the following stack trace?:

```
ERROR | Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ResourceLoader must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.<init>(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:72)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:377)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:225)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:632)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at logging.Service.main(Service.java:12)
 WARN | Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1534f01b: startup date [Fri Feb 26 16:14:34 UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at logging.Service.main(Service.java:12)
Exception in thread "main"  WARN | Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1534f01b: startup date [Fri Feb 26 16:14:34 UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ResourceLoader must not be null at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)

    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.<init>(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.javaat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at logging.Service.main(Service.java:12)

    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:377)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:225)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:632)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at logging.Service.main(Service.java:12)
```

Here is the source in question:

```
package logging;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class Service 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Service.class, args);
    }
}
```

And here is the dependency info from build.gradle:

```
configurations {
  compile.exclude group:'ch.qos.logback'
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.activemq', name: 'activemq-all', version: '5.12.0'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: '1.2.1.RELEASE' 
    compile("org.springframework:spring-jms")
}
```

I have tried deleting ~/.gradle/caches but that didn't help. Could it be a conflicting version of spring or another library? Not sure where to look or how to fix.

Comment: Where do you define your ActiveMQ params?

Comment: Inside an application.properties file found in a resources directory within the jar.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the activemq-all module. Changing it to activemq-core fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I just removed the spring elastic search dependency in my pom.xml, then it started to work for me.

If you suppose to use the spring elastic search dependency, try to change the version and try it.